# How to configure elasticsearch 5

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

How to configure elasticsearch 5 TransportClient.

Now TransportClient is abstract class. I found only PreBuiltTransportClient, this is the new way to configure elasticsearch Client ?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can find that in the [official documentation for 5.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/master/transport-client.html) as well

```
Settings settings = Settings.builder()
   .put("cluster.name", "ElasticSearchClusterName");

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host1"), 9300))
        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("host2"), 9300));
```

It is worth nothing that the `PreBuiltTransportClient` is [pre-configured](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/a62740bbd2f5657cf1f2cf38b21d3f2c1d38d09e/client/transport/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/transport/client/PreBuiltTransportClient.java#L57-L61) with the following modules:

- Netty3
- Netty4
- Reindex
- Percolator
- Mustache

Also make sure that you have a dependency on the `transport` artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Where do you specify the cluster?

Comment: Thank you. For my local elastic server had to also add settings.put("client.transport.sniff", false) Added a config for this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

First download respective jar file and keep that in lib folder and add them to build path.
You can follow below code to configure it:

```
 Settings settings = Settings.builder()
    .put("cluster.name", "ElasticSearchClusterName")
    //.put("client.transport.sniff", true)
    //.put("shield.user", elasticUserName+":"+elasticPassword)
    .build();

TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings)
                                  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(elasticHostOne, elasticTransportPort))
                                  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(elasticHostTwo, elasticTransportPort))
                                  .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(elasticHostThree, elasticTransportPort));
```