# Using PreBuiltTransportClient with elasticsearch 5

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to follow the official Elasticsearch 5 documentation for setting up a transport client:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.0/transport-client.html

However, using the package org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:5.0.0-rc1, the class PreBuiltTransportClient does not appear to be anywhere in my path. It doesn't appear to exist. What should I do to configure a TransportClient? Do I need a separate package? Am I using the wrong version in Maven?

Thanks.

Comment: This answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38883784/how-to-configure-elasticsearch-5

Comment: Already saw that. The problem is that the class in question, PreBuiltTransportClient, isn't in the jar.

Comment: You need to add a dependency on the `transport` artifact: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/transport

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add a dependency on the `transport` artifact:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0-beta1</version>
</dependency>
```